# Python DUP broadcast sender/receiver and broadcast IP address function

Tags: python, udp

from broadcast sender

```
import socket, traceback

host = ''                               # Bind to all interfaces
port = 51423
broadcastaddr=findbroadcastaddr();
addr=(broadcastaddr, port)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)                
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)   #broadcasr

data='hello from sender'

s.bind('', port)                  #socket binding to any host
s.sendto(data, addr):
s.close
```

1)
This is a broadcast sender, I don't know the findbroadcastaddr function, basically if my network address is 192.1.3.0 then my broadcast address would be 192.1.3.255. Anybody know that function.

broadcast receiver
i

```
mport socket

# Set the socket parameters
addr = ('', 33333)  # host, port

# Create socket and bind to address
UDPSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)

# Receive messages
while True:
    data, addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(1024)
```

2)1024 is the maximum number of data of bytes can be received. and the result from recvfrom breaks down into 2 fields ; the first part is data and second is where it comes from?

Answer (score 2):

The following calculates a LAN broadcast address given the local machine's IP.  It sets the 4th octet to 255, so host on **192.168.1.12** will get a LAN broadcast IP of **192.168.1.255**

```
from socket import *

myip = gethostbyname(gethostname())
print 'My IP',myip

# XX: assumes /24 address
broadip = inet_ntoa( inet_aton(myip)[:3] + b'\xff' )
print 'LAN broadcast', broadip
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the [answer provided by *johntellsall*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24019746), which merely "sets the 4th octet to 255".

You intend to calculate the broadcast address correctly, it depends on your *netmask* and not only your IP address.  In *some cases* it may come down to setting the 4th octet to *0xFF*.

The proper steps to calculate a broadcast address are:

1. binary negate the netmask
2. take the result and then *OR* it with the host IP address